# Why my database is still empty after I seed it in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity

In an ASP.NET Core MVC web app using Entity Framework, I defined my models as follows:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NewTechParentPortalV3.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Last name cannot be longer than 50 
characters.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 
50 characters.")]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", 
ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public int ParentID { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    }

    public class Parent
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Last name cannot be longer than 50 
characters.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 
50 characters.")]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I updated the database context, and seeded the database with test data. After that, I added migrations, changed the connection string to make a new one and then updated the database. But when I open the database, it is empty?

Note: I was able to seed database correctly before I add navigation properties to both models, I mean before adding the following codes to Student model:

```
            public Parent Parent { get; set; }
```

and adding the following codes to Parent model:

```
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

It shows that I did the other parts correctly, but when I add the above lines of code, the database becomes empty. Can anyone help me find out the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to confirm :

1. Have you defined the relationships for those navigational properties, like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().HasMany(g => g.Students);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

2. Have you assigned values to each other when seeding

```
var parentId = 1;
var student = new Student
{
  ParentId = parentId
}
....

var parent = new Parent()
{
  ID = parentId
  Students = {student}
}
```

Comment: I had already done part 2, but i had not assigned part 1. I did part 1 but still database is empty...

Comment: Debug the seeding code, you should be able to see the local values before they are committed to the Db.

Comment: Thank you! after debugging the seeding code, I found the problem! In the seeding code, the Parent table should be filled first, and then the Student table because the Student table includes ParentID and has a Parent navigation property. So, although I assigned values to ParentID since I had not assigned it at that time (it was assigned after Student table), therefore it could not find the related navigation property and put Null in it. That caused error and prevented filling database tables.